# Google cloud load balancer doing too many redirects

Tags: google-cloud-platform

[image]I am using load balancer of Google cloud, which will forward request to my site. I am getting too many redirect error for contact us URI

```
1) https://<direct machine IP>/contactus  -- OK
2) https://<loadbalancer IP>  -- OK
3) https://<loadbalncer IP>/pdf -- OK
4) https://<loadbalncer IP>/contactus --> too many redirect error
```

Comment: So, do you have a question or is this just information?

Comment: This is a question....How to fix too many redirect error for Point#4?

Comment: So add your question to the original question so people don’t have to trawl through comments trying to piece together what you are asking.

Comment: We need more info, send screenshots of the Load Balancer configuration.

Comment: Added the image in the question. Let me know if any additional detail will be required

Comment: It looks like you are using redirection application/web server level. That redirection might be based on the host header. As such I would recommend posting your redirection so that we could suggest you a workaround. 
I would also suggest trying to use a [Network Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network/setting-up-network) to see if you are receiving the same error.

I would also request you to post your findings in ‘Server Fault’ as ‘Stack Overflow’ is for  programming and development questions.